# log of remote access to windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

is there a way to get a log of all users accessed the windows2008 r2 server remotely

we need to know their machine IP from what time to what time they have accessed the server
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These events are recorded in the Security event-log. Event ID 4846. Logout events are ID 4634. You can correlate login events with logout events through the LogonGUID attribute on both events.

Windows doesn't provide a way to generate a list with these, you'll have to write something or buy something to do it. `wevtutil` provides a way of querying the event-log and dumping it to a text file for processing with a script.

Comment: Note 1. logon/off events are not logged by default: use `secpol.msc` (or GP) to enable. 2. PowerShell's `Get-WinEvent` allows remote access to filter and read event logs, including all the processing and saving PSH can then do; see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/24/use-powershell-cmdlet-to-filter-event-log-for-easy-parsing.aspx) for starting on that cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:
1. Using free software
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.05.utilityspotlight.aspx
also keep track of all logins information in Active Directory domains

2.Using paid monitoring software: 
terminalserviceslog.com

3.Using login script
You can add some lines to the logon and log off script to write something to the server share log file.

@echo off
echo [%date%  %time%] >>\server\share\logtime.log
echo %username% log on %computername% to domain: %userdomain% >>\server\share\logon.log